# Crear Grupos de datos con Linq

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

tengo una duda con linq. aquí consulto un grupo de usuarios, en este caso llegan 250.

```
var usuarios = _db.usuariosmv10.Where(x => x.campana.Equals(id)).ToList();
```

Entonces, en la variable usuarios tengo una lista de 250 usuarios, ahora que es lo que necesito.

Quiero poder agrupar esos 250 usuarios en grupos de 50, osea que me quede en una variable una lista de 5 donde esos 5 contengan 50 usuarios, como es posible?

Agradezco la asesoría.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
var usuariosAgrupados = usuarios.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 50)
                                .Select(x => x.Select(m => m.Value).ToList())
                                .ToList();
```

Breve explicación: Primero se crea una nueva lista, en la cual se añade a la lista original el índice de cada elemento. Luego se realiza un agrupamiento por índice(cada 50 elementos). Finalmente se obtienen los elementos de esta nueva lista agrupada.

Comment: Agrega una explicación al código mi estimado, así todos los que estén aprendiendo estarán agradecidos contigo :D Saludos.

Comment: huy 4D1C70 eso está estupendo, muchas gracias!!!! Monstruo ese codigo, hace justo lo que quiero y adicional aprendi algo nuevo. Muchas Gracias!!